# Firebase get the first and last name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My Question:

I made a little Android App, where you can sign up and login with the firebase auth system.
I made it like:

```
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

then i used firebaseAuth.signinwithEmailAndPassword. Now my question: can i get the First name and the Last name from the user's email account?
Like in youtube at the comments: example:

> Firstname Lastname: Nice video

That not the email address is here, but the First and Last name,
Greetings

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user's name from their profile. From the [Firebase documentation on reading the user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile):

> To get a user's profile information, use the accessor methods of an instance of `FirebaseUser`. For example:
>
> ```
> FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
> if (user != null) {
>     // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
>     String name = user.getDisplayName();
>     String email = user.getEmail();
>     Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
>
>     // Check if user's email is verified
>     boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();
>
>    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
>     // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
>     // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
>     String uid = user.getUid();
> }
> ```

Comment: thank you, I already knew this, and this is not that, what i want to get :/

Comment: In that case you might want to clarify your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there a way to get the first name only? You can probably get that if you split the string at each space, however there are some names (such as Japanese) that do not have a space.